is there a way to tell if the formula contains specific function inside?
I have a formula f <- ~ poly(xxx, degree = 2) and would like to know if there is a way to tell the formula uses poly() as a function inside the formula.
I am working on a package and want user to give a warning if they try to use stats or base package operation in the formula on certain cases.

The development version of the reformulas package (not yet on CRAN though ...) will do this.
remotes::install_github("bbolker/reformulas")
library(reformulas)
anySpecial(y ~ poly, specials = "poly")     ## FALSE
anySpecial(y ~ poly(1), specials = "poly")  ## TRUE


My answer handles that just fine. It will fail if the user does ~ poly(poly, degree = 2) but that is easily fixed (see my edit). But you can't anticipate everything a user might come up with. E.g., try to handle ~ do.call("poly", list(x1, x2)).

1) all.vars Use all.vars with functions=TRUE as shown.  This alternative does not distinguish between a function poly and a variable of the same name but it is unlikely that anyone would use that as a variable name and it is very short. If that edge case is important to handle then use one of the other alternatives below.
f <- ~ poly(xxx, degree = 2)
"poly" %in% all.vars(f, functions = TRUE)
## [1] TRUE

"poly" %in% all.vars(y ~ x, functions = TRUE)
## [1] FALSE

2) terms We can use terms to extract the info and then test it.
any_poly2 <- function(x) {
  x |>
    terms() |>
    attr("variables") |>
    sapply(\(x) inherits(x, "call") && x[[1]] == as.name("poly")) |>
    any()
}

any_poly2(y ~ poly(x))
## [1] TRUE

any_poly2(y ~ poly + x)
## [1] FALSE

3) recursive We can develop a short recursive function which walks the parse tree of the formula looking for a poly function call.
any_poly3 <- function(e) {
  if (is.symbol(e) || is.numeric(e)) FALSE
  else if (inherits(e, "call") & identical(e[[1]], as.name("poly"))) TRUE
  else any(sapply(e, any_poly3))
}    

any_poly3(y ~ poly(x))
## [1] TRUE

any_poly3(y ~ poly + x)
## [1] FALSE

4) getParseData. We can search the output from R's parser with the getParseData function in the utils package after reparsing the input. The utils package comes with R so it does not need to be installed. That function produces a data frame with one row per token with information that includes the text of each input token (text) and the type of the token (token) .
library(utils)
    
any_poly4 <- function(x) {
     x |>
       deparse1() |>
       parse(text = _, keep.source = TRUE) |>
       getParseData() |>
       with(any(text == "poly" &
          token == "SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL"))
}

any_poly4(y ~ poly(x))
## [1] TRUE

any_poly4(y ~ x + poly)
## [1] FALSE


all.vars is not quite correct. ie if you have a variable called poly it will give true. eg "poly" %in% all.vars(~cbind(poly, x))

I would say that is an edge case of no practical importance and are out-weighted by the brevity of the solution but if it were wanted then all the other alternatives in the answer do handle that.  I have added examples illustrating it.

f <- ~ poly(xxx, degree = 2)
setdiff(all.names(f), c(all.vars(f), "~"))
#[1] "poly"

f <- ~ I(xxx^2)
setdiff(all.names(f), c(all.vars(f), "~"))
#[1] "I" "^"

Edit:
If you need to handle stuff like f <- ~ poly(poly, degree = 2):
sum("poly" == all.names(f)) > sum("poly" == all.vars(f))
#[1] TRUE


I think you should be able to use grepl here, with the pattern poly\\(.
For example:
df <- data.frame(dist=rnorm(100), polygon=rnorm(100))

m <- lm(dist ~ poly(polygon, 2), data = df)
f <- formula(m)
any(grepl("poly\\(", f)) # returns TRUE

while:
m <- lm(dist ~ polygon, data = df)
f <- formula(m)
any(grepl("poly\\(", f)) # returns FALSE


I realise that a data frame could have a column called "poly(", but it's highly unlikely.
